# How to make a string out of a hashed code in java?

Tags: java, string, hash, hashcode

I know how string.hashCode() in java works:

```
    public int hashCode() {
        int h = hash;
        if (h == 0 && value.length > 0) {
            char val[] = value;

            for (int i = 0; i < value.length; i++) {
                h = 31 * h + val[i];
            }
            hash = h;
        }
        return h;
    }
```

assume we have a hash code like "119193" corresponding to "xyz".
Is there any way to **unhash it and find the real string**?

Comment: If you can do that then it's not called `hash` anymore.

Comment: no, there is not. Different Strings can have the same hash code.

Comment: int has a finite number of values it can have while there is no limit of the possible Strings you can create. So it should be self-explanatory why you cannot have a 1-to-1 mapping from every possible String to a unique int.

Answer (score 0):

Hash functions are designed to be one way only.

As you are converting a theoretically infinitely large input group (all possible Strings) into a finite number of integers it is inevitable that multiple different Strings will result in the same hash.

That said, you can theoretically test a large number of Strings and check if the new hash matches the stored hash. Nevertheless, you can never be sure that this String is the same as the original input, as multiple Strings can result in the same hash.

If you have a finite amount of input Strings (i.e. from a predefined pool) or you can narrow down the test search i.e. to a combination of words from a dictionary you can cut down the time it would take for testing the hash.